# BS4: Google Next Page "Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

While able to successfully scrape the first page, it does not allow me to do the second. Please note that I do not want to do this with Selinum.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://google.com/search?q=In+order+to&hl=en'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

page = 1
while True:
    print()
    print('Page {}...'.format(page))
    print('-' * 80)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    for h in soup.select('h3'):
        print(h.get_text(strip=True))

    next_link = soup.select_one('a:contains("Next")')
    if not next_link:
        break

    url = 'https://google.com' + next_link['href']
    page += 1
```

Result:

```
Page 1...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
In order to Synonyms, In order to Antonyms | Thesaurus.com
In order to - English Grammar Today - Cambridge Dictionary
in order to - Wiktionary
What is another word for "in order to"? - WordHippo
In Order For (someone or something) To | Definition of In ...
In Order For | Definition of In Order For by Merriam-Webster
In order to definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionary
Using "in order to" in English - English Study Page
IN ORDER (FOR SOMEONE / SOMETHING ) TO DO ...
262 In Order To synonyms - Other Words for In Order To
Searches related to In order to
Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.
```

The error lies here:

```
next_link = soup.select_one('a:contains("Next")')
```

Comment: Try a different parser, I know lxml can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lxml` as a parser instead of `html.parser`

Install it with `pip install lxml`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://google.com/search?q=In+order+to&hl=en'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

page = 1
while True:
    print()
    print('Page {}...'.format(page))
    print('-' * 80)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'lxml')
    for h in soup.select('h3'):
        print(h.get_text(strip=True))

    next_link = soup.select_one('a:contains("Next")')
    if not next_link:
        break

    url = 'https://google.com' + next_link['href']
    page += 1
```